# How to repeat the input options in console using `input()` until the user chooses to quit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am providing multiple options to the user to choose from using `input()` in Python 3. I want the options to be displayed again and again until the user chooses to quit by selecting the quit option

**For example :**

```
a = 5
b = 2 
inp = input('''Please choose from Options mentioned below:
        1. Sum
        2. Multiply
        3. Divide
        0. Quit
        ''')
    
    if int(inp) == 1:
        sum(a,b)
    elif int(inp) == 2:
        multiply(a,b)
    elif int(inp) == 3:
        divide(a,b)
    elif int(inp) == 0:
        print("Thanks for your input.\nQuitting the process")
    elif int(inp) > 3:
        print("Please type numbers from 0 to 8")
    else:
        print("Only numbers are accepted. Please select right option")
```

So, as per the above example, the same options have to be displayed to the user until the user enters "0" which will quit the `input()` process from the console. If the user enters a number > 3 or if the user enters any non-numerical characters then the relevant message should be printed and also the options have to be shown again.

**Right now, in case of these failures, only the message is getting printed on the screen and it's ending the input() process.**

Any idea what am I missing here ?

Comment: You can use `while` loop.

Comment: IIUC, why not use an infinite while loop? You would just call break when the user selects quit.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
while True:
    inp = input('''Please choose from Options mentioned below:
        1. Sum
        2. Multiply
        3. Divide
        0. Quit
        ''')

    if int(inp) == 1:
        sum(a,b)
    elif int(inp) == 2:
        multiply(a,b)
    elif int(inp) == 3:
        divide(a,b)
    elif int(inp) == 0:
        print("Thanks for your input.\nQuitting the process")
        break
    elif int(inp) > 3:
        print("Please type numbers from 0 to 8")
    else:
        print("Only numbers are accepted. Please select right option")
```

Although this answers your question, I must say iteration and branching are core concepts in programming, so I recommend you to follow some courses or series of tutorials instead of asking questions from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @adnanmuttaleb for prompt response.  I know of loops. I was thinking of a solution to redirect to same input options only in case of errors. Something like try catch exception scenario instead of infinite loops.